# inspect module not found for python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

```
ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal$ pyenv local 3.6.0

ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal$ sudo virtualenv env

> Using base prefix
> '/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0' New python executable in
> /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env/bin/python3.6
> Not overwriting existing python script
> /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env/bin/python
> (you must use
> /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env/bin/python3.6)
> Failed to import the site module Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File
> "/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env/lib/python3.6/site.py",
> line 67, in <module>
>     import os   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env/lib/python3.6/os.py",
> line 57, in <module>
>     import posixpath as path   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py",
> line 73, in <module>
>     import inspect ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inspect' ERROR: The executable
> /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env/bin/python3.6
> is not functioning ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is
> '/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal'
> (should be
> '/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal/env')
> ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable



ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/cnn-removal$ pip3 install -U  inspect

> Collecting inspect   Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement inspect (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
> for inspect
```

Comment: [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) is part of the Python STD library, you don't need to install it externally. Maybe `pyenv` failed in building up the right environment. Did you use `pyenv` to install Python 3.6?

Comment: yes `pyenv install 3.6.0`